# rails, locale not working in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

In my application there is a form, a simpleform (is it relevant?) that shows some date fields:

```
<% f.input :my_date_field :as => :string %>
```

I want the date to be formatted in my locale, that is:

```
31/12/2013
```

while instead i get:

```
2013-06-25 13:47:00
```

I've tried to solve the problem setting a fix locale for my application, that is, in my application controller i've set:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = :it
  end

  end
```

So it should set the locale to :it regardless what the browser says.

No result. The questions here are two. Who does the convertion of a date to a string, and how can I influence it?

Comment: Yes, it did. I just give some time before accepting it to see if there are further evolutions.

Comment: Allright don't hesitate to ask if you encounter other problems related to this question ;)